# Drupal Views Entity Reference Limiting results

Tags: drupal, view

I have a lot of experience with Drupal 7 views but I am running into a roadblock and I am wondering if what I want to do is even possible.

Here is the scenario. I have two content types - **Game** and **Score**.

Scores reference Games via entity reference. I want to create a view that shows all of the games. Easy of course. Then I added the relationship to bridge to the content that is referencing game. This allows me to pull score field data into the view fine.

Here is the issue: Now I want to limit the view to show each game node only once regardless of how many score nodes exist that reference it. I only want the score that is the highest to be displayed with the game.

Is this clear? I need some sort of aggregation on the score nodes data I believe.

Comment: For this its better to use PHP Field and add your logic there.

Comment: For Global PHP field : https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php